# Why do we need a conditional equals operator?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

Why do we need to differentiate between an assignment and a boolean condition, as in the '=' vs '==' operators? Wouldn't context be enough to prevent ambiguity? Is there an example of when it would be ambiguous? It's not really a programming question, but I find it to be interesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "it's not really a programming question".

Comment: It depends on what contexts your language handles. How would you interpret `a = b = c`? Is `a` now equal to `b`, `c`, or the result of comparing `b` and `c` for equality? Or is it strictly a Boolean expression, checking if `a`, `b`, and `c` are equal?

Comment: Looks like it is a computer science question.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the language. But in C for example, an assignment is an expression that has a value, not a statement.
Hence

```
if(a = b)
```

is valid code, and evaluates to true whenever `b` was nonzero (i. e. `true` in the sense of C) before this code, and as well assigns the old value of b to a.
On the other hand,

```
if(a == b)
```

is only true if `a` and `b` have the same values, and does not do an assignment.

Languages "inherited" from C, like Java and C#, kept this logic, but reduced the potential of errors by requiring that a condition must have type boolean. Hence my first example will cause an compiler error (as long as `a` and `b` are not Boolean variables).